# Can we submit a table in post request using JSP/Servlets?

Tags: java, post

Can i submit table in posting form to server in JSP?

I am creating table dynamically.

User fills a form and click a button and all value in form become row of table.

While click of submit button i want to read the table and create put value to List. Is it possible?

Comment: can u tell us, which technologies u r using?

Comment: so, u want to submit the form using java script, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

First you'll have to think of a way to represent your table on the wire.  Probably some json representation will make sense.

Then, to submit the table, build up a javascript object, and make an ajax call to your server, with that object as the payload (in json). (I would suggest using JQuery for this, but you could roll your own).

On the server side unmarshal the json and add the entries to your list.

Alternatively, add a rowindex to every input's name and submit the table as a normal form.  Then on the server side, you'll need to iterate over the posted values and find out how many rows there are.

The json solution will probably be easier to maintain though.

Comment: Thanks for great suggestion.